# How i display date according to culture using date.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date, datetime

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
</system.web>
```

```
alert(Date.parse(serverDay + "." + serverMonth + "." + serverYear).toString("dd.MMM.yyyy"));
```

i have pass `serverDay=06 ,serverMonth=01 ,serverYear=2014` (its just example) from c#.
 now i have to display date according to culture.
 i have two date.js `date-en-US.js` and `date-hi-IN.js`

when i set hindi js it gives me correct result `06.जनवरी.2014`
 but when i load english js  it gives me incorrect result `01.Jun.2014`.

Comment: Have you searched on Google regarding your question properly??

Answer (score 0):

In date-en-US.js, you will notice that the culture format pattern for shortDate is **"M/d/yyyy"**, and the intput date was parsed as that pattern, so the specified serverDay became a month and serverMonth became a day.

If you don't want to edit the day and month position when pass value to Date.parse method, you can edit shortDate value in date-en-US.js.
Otherwise, you can change culture to be **en-GB** (using date-en-GB.js) instead, because the shortDate for this culture is **"dd/MM/yyyy"**.